# how to add " to end of specific lines in linux

Tags: linux, sed, formatting, text-formatting

I have a file as below

```
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:25.388Z","duration":0.8255,"error":0
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:26.809Z","duration":0.29521,"error":0,"state":"pending
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:29.053Z","duration":2.90688,"error":0,"options":"merge_request.create
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:00.635Z","duration":0.46049,"error":0
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:39.351Z","duration":0.76487,"error":0,"state":"failed
```

I want to add " at the end but only to lines ending as a string

I gave `sed -i 's/$/",/' filename` but it adds quotes to end of all the lines.

Desired output is

```
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:25.388Z","duration":0.8255,"error":0
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:26.809Z","duration":0.29521,"error":0,"state":"pending"
"time":"2022-301T12:00:29.053Z","duration":2.90688,"error":0,"push_options":"merge_request.create"
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:00.635Z","duration":0.46049,"error":0
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:39.351Z","duration":0.76487,"error":0,"state":"failed"
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/:"[^"]*$/&"/' file > tmp && mv tmp file
sed -i 's/:"[^"]*$/&"/' file # GNU sed
```

The `'s/:"[^"]*$/&"/'` command means:

- `:"[^"]*$` - matches a `:"` substring and then zero or more chars other than `"` till end of string
- `&"` - replaces the match with itself and a `"` char.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ha4KJH):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:25.388Z","duration":0.8255,"error":0
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:26.809Z","duration":0.29521,"error":0,"state":"pending
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:29.053Z","duration":2.90688,"error":0,"options":"merge_request.create
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:00.635Z","duration":0.46049,"error":0
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:39.351Z","duration":0.76487,"error":0,"state":"failed'
 
sed 's/:"[^"]*$/&"/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:25.388Z","duration":0.8255,"error":0
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:26.809Z","duration":0.29521,"error":0,"state":"pending"
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:29.053Z","duration":2.90688,"error":0,"options":"merge_request.create"
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:00.635Z","duration":0.46049,"error":0
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:39.351Z","duration":0.76487,"error":0,"state":"failed"
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting an `awk` solution:

```
awk '/[[:alpha:]]$/{$0=$0"\""}1' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[a-z]$/&"/' input_file
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:25.388Z","duration":0.8255,"error":0
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:26.809Z","duration":0.29521,"error":0,"state":"pending"
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:29.053Z","duration":2.90688,"error":0,"options":"merge_request.create"
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:00.635Z","duration":0.46049,"error":0
"time":"2022-03-01T12:00:39.351Z","duration":0.76487,"error":0,"state":"failed"
```